# What are the arguments against atheism in Crime and Punishment?

Tags: russian-language, fyodor-dostoyevsky, crime-and-punishment

I'm trying to figure out exactly what arguments Dostoevsky tries to make in *Crime and Punishment* against atheism. I'm talking about the kind of conclusion he wants you to make for yourself when reading his story. How does he show his thoughts in the actions of his characters?

I know this is an impossible question to properly answer. But I really just want to know what some of the possible interpretations that are out there are.